# Django models: How do I access children from parent models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-template-filters

I need to query the following model so I get, an output in the following form, where parents are listed alphabetically, then their children are listed immediately below parents alphabetically too.

```
aparent
 -aparentchild
 -bchild
 -zchild
  -achildchild
  -xchildchild
bparent
 -xchild
cparent
 -achild
 -schild


class Category(BaseTimeModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_FIELD, blank=False, null=False, unique=True, help_text=HELP_TEXT)
    level = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, related_name="parents")
    details = models.CharField(max_length=DETAIL_FIELD, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        permissions = (
            ("view_category", "Can view category"),
        )
```

Some sample data are as follows.

```
    Name        Level  Parent
   Bleh          0     Null         
   Category A    0     Null
   Tshirts       0     Null
   tt shirts     1     Tshirts
   butt shirts   1     Tshirts
   v necked      2     tt shirts
```

Level 0 is parent, 1 indicates child, 2 indicates grandchild and so on.

To get the parents via name, the following query gives

```
Category.objects.filter(level=0).order_by("name") 

Bleh
Category A
Tshirts
```

How do I get the children? Hint please or link to docs.

UPDATE:

I want,

```
  Bleh
   Category A
   Tshirts
    -butt shirts
    -tt shirts
     -v necked
```

And, I have accessed the children by setting a property in the model,

```
@property
def get_children(self):
    return self.parents.all().order_by("name")
```

And, in the listview of the model,

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object }} 
   {% if object.get_children %}
       {% for obj in object.get_children %}
             {{ obj }}
              ....
               and so on for further deep children.....
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, this is not DRY. Hint please.

Comment: What is the expected output for the sample data you posted?

Comment: @RahulGupta Updates are posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt), which is designed for working with recursive models in Django.

Swap your model's `ForeignKey` with `TreeForeignKey`, e.g:

```
class Category(MPTTModel, BaseTimeModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_FIELD, blank=False, null=False, unique=True, help_text=HELP_TEXT)
    level = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.TreeForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, related_name="children")
    details = models.CharField(max_length=DETAIL_FIELD, blank=True, null=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        level_attr = 'level'
```

`level_attr` will contain the object's level in the hierarchy, e.g. `0` for the top-most parent.

Taking an example from the documentation, your template would look something like this:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}

<ul class="root">
{% recursetree nodes %}
    <li>
        {{ node.name }}
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul class="children">
                {{ children }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

Refer to [this tutorial](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html#the-problem) for more information, their example is pretty similar to your own use case.